# Interchanging limit operators

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, solution-verification

> We know that $\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}X(k)=X$. Show that
> $$
> \lim\limits_{k\to\infty}\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sum\limits_{l=1}^nP\left(X(k)\geq l\right)=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}\sum\limits_{l=1}^nP\left(X(k)\geq l\right)
> $$
> Hint: $P\left(X(k)\geq l\right)\leq P\left(X\geq l\right)$ for all $l\in\mathbb{N}$ and $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}\sum\limits_{l=1}^nP\left(X(k)\geq l\right)$ exists.

---

**My approach:**

In order to show that we are allowed to interchange the limits we must show that for an arbitrary $\epsilon>0$ we find a $k_0\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for all $k>k_0$ we have
$$
\left|\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sum\limits_{l=1}^nP\left(X(k)\geq l\right)-\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}\sum\limits_{l=1}^nP\left(X(k)\geq l\right)\right|<\epsilon.
$$
We start with some manipulations:
$\begin{align*}
&\left|\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sum\limits_{l=1}^nP\left(X(k)\geq l\right)+\sum\limits_{l=1}^mP\left(X(k)\geq l\right)-\sum\limits_{l=1}^mP\left(X(k)\geq l\right)-\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}\sum\limits_{l=1}^nP\left(X(k)\geq l\right)\right|\\
&\leq\left|\sum\limits_{l=m}^{\infty}P\left(X(k)\geq l\right)\right|+\left|\sum\limits_{l=1}^mP\left(X(k)\geq l\right)-\sum\limits_{l=1}^{\infty}P\left(X\geq l\right)\right|\\
&\leq \left|\sum\limits_{l=m}^{\infty}P\left(X\geq l\right)\right|+\left|\sum\limits_{l=1}^mP\left(X(k)\geq l\right)+\sum\limits_{l=1}^mP\left(X\geq l\right)-\sum\limits_{l=1}^mP\left(X\geq l\right)-\sum\limits_{l=1}^{\infty}P\left(X\geq l\right)\right|\\
&\leq 2\left|\sum\limits_{l=m}^{\infty}P\left(X\geq l\right)\right|+\left|\sum\limits_{l=1}^mP\left(X(k)\geq l\right)-P\left(X\geq l\right)\right|.
\end{align*}$
Due to the existence of $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}\sum\limits_{l=1}^nP\left(X(k)\geq l\right)$ we find a $m_0\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for all $m>m_0$ the left summand gets arbitrary small, i.e. $<\frac{\epsilon}{4}$. Note that the left summand doesn't depend on $k$. In order to shrink the right summand, we use the fact that $\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}X(k)=X$. So we find a $k_0\in\mathbb{N}$, such that for all $k>k_0$ the right summand is $<\frac{\epsilon}{2m_0}$. Hence, $\epsilon>0$ is an upper bound which shows the statement at the beginning.

---

Are there some fundamental flaws in this proof? My tutor has deducted 50% of my point without any further justification.

Comment: I think what's flawed is that you used the hint without actually showing/justifying what the hint gives you, but I could be wrong.

Comment: @BrunoB, I am not sure what you exactly mean. The second inequaity sign uses $P\left(X(k)\geq l\right)\leq P\left(X\geq l\right)$ and at the end I simply used the existence of the limit $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}\sum\limits_{l=1}^nP\left(X(k)\geq l\right)$ and the definition of a limit.

Comment: What I mean is that you have to explain why those things are true in the first place.

Comment: @BrunoB, we can use the hint whithout proof.

Comment: I don't really see anything wrong with your proof if you can indeed use the hint without proof (outside of "the right summand is $<\frac{\epsilon}{2m_0}$" when it's $<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ but that's pretty much a non-issue since it's easy to see what you meant), so you should probably double-check with your tutor whether it was because of the hint not having been justified or not.